# Lodash search array item in other array item

Tags: javascript, angularjs, arrays, search, find

Hello i'm using lodash library.

I want to search if phone in receivedMessagesMock is in contactsMocks phone

If receivedMessagesMock.phone === contactsMocks.phoneNumbers.value I need to push the contactsMocks.name.formatted in the same receivedMessagesMock position.

Something like

```
if(receivedMessagesMock[0].phone === contactsMocks.phoneNumbers.value {
 receivedMessagesMock[0].name = contactsMocks.name.formatted;
}
```

The contactMock and receivedMessagesMock

```
var contactsMock = [{'id':'1','rawId':'1','displayName':'Asd','name':{'givenName':'Asd','formatted':'Asd'},'nickname':null,'phoneNumbers':[{'id':'1','pref':false,'value':'000000000','type':'mobile', 'loggedInSystem':true}],'emails':null,'addresses':null,'ims':null,'organizations':null,'birthday':null,'note':null,'photos':null,'categories':null,'urls':null},{'id':'2','rawId':'2','displayName':'Bbb','name':{'givenName':'Bbb','formatted':'Bbb'},'nickname':null,'phoneNumbers':[{'id':'3','pref':false,'value':'565 65 65 65','type':'mobile'}],'emails':null,'addresses':null,'ims':null,'organizations':null,'birthday':null,'note':null,'photos':null,'categories':null,'urls':null},{'id':'3','rawId':'3','displayName':'Ccc','name':{'givenName':'Ccc','formatted':'Ccc'},'nickname':null,'phoneNumbers':[{'id':'5','pref':false,'value':'0000000001','type':'mobile'}],'emails':null,'addresses':null,'ims':null,'organizations':null,'birthday':null,'note':null,'photos':null,'categories':null,'urls':null},{'id':'4','rawId':'4','displayName':'Ddd','name':{'givenName':'Ddd','formatted':'Ddd'},'nickname':null,'phoneNumbers':[{'id':'6','pref':false,'value':'000 00 00 01','type':'mobile'}],'emails':null,'addresses':null,'ims':null,'organizations':null,'birthday':null,'note':null,'photos':null,'categories':null,'urls':null}];

    var receivedMessagesMock = [{
        'id': 12,
        'phone': '000 00 00 01',
        'time': '15:44',
        'priority': 1,
        'response' : false
    },{
        'id': 15,
        'phone': '000 00 00 01',
        'time': '15:44',
        'priority': 1,
        'response' : false
    },{
        'id': 16,
        'phone': '000 00 00 01',
        'time': '15:44',
        'priority': 2,
        'response' : true
    }
    ];
```

Comment: And the question/problem is?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is one way to do this using lodash:

```
lodash.map(receivedMessagesMock, function(rmm) {
  var foundContact = lodash.find(contactsMock, function(cm) {
    return lodash.find(cm.phoneNumbers, function(pn) {
      return pn.value == rmm.phone;
    });
  });
  if (foundContact) {
    rmm.names = foundContact.name.formatted
  }
  return rmm;
});
```

Keep in mind, you asked for a name (singular) to be inserted into the received messages. This means that if two or more contacts in the list have the same number, for whatever reason, the above will always return the first match. But there is a real possibility that there will be more than one match, so it might be appropriate to insert an array of names.

```
lodash.map(receivedMessagesMock, function(rmm) {
  var foundContacts = lodash.filter(contactsMock, function(cm) {
    return lodash.find(cm.phoneNumbers, function(pn) {
      return pn.value == rmm.phone;
    });
  });
  if (foundContacts.length > 0) {
    rmm.names = lodash.map(foundContacts, function(fcs) {
      return name.formatted
    });
  }
  return rmm;
});
```

Comment: You save my day @JoelCDoyle. thanks for your time :)

Comment: Hi again @JoelCDoyle
How can I return the phoneNumber if pn.value != rmm.phone; return pn.value ¿?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by "return the phoneNumber". `pn` is only in scope inside the context of the `lodash.find` predicate function that it is defined in. The returned statement of that function will be evaluated as a boolean to determine if it is a match, nothing more.

Comment: When pn.value == rmm.phone is not true I want that the 'name.formatted' = to pn.value